# View::make doesn't return a data from controller to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

```
public function getList()
{
    $posts=\Posts::allPosts();
    $this->layout->content=\View::make('admin.posts.list', $posts);
}
```

So I'm sending the `$posts` array to my view, but I get an error when I try to `var_dump(...)` it that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should inform the variable name to Blade:

```
public function getList()
{
    $posts=\Posts::allPosts();
    $this->layout->content=\View::make('admin.posts.list', array('posts' => $posts));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom to use an $data array.

```
public function getList()
{
    $data = array(
        'posts' => Posts::allPosts(),
        'morestuff' => $variable,
    );

    $this->layout->content=\View::make('admin.posts.list')->with($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do here could be to use `compact()`

```
public function getList()
{
    $posts = \Posts::allPosts();

    $this->layout->content = \View::make('admin.posts.list', compact('posts'));
}
```

It does basically the same as `array('posts' => $posts)`